# Preferred method to store PHP arrays (json_encode vs serialize)

Tags: php, performance, arrays, json, serialization

I need to store a multi-dimensional associative array of data in a flat file for caching purposes. I might occasionally come across the need to convert it to JSON for use in my web app but the vast majority of the time I will be using the array directly in PHP.

Would it be more efficient to store the array as JSON or as a PHP serialized array in this text file? I've looked around and it seems that in the newest versions of PHP (5.3), `json_decode` is actually faster than `unserialize`.

I'm currently leaning towards storing the array as JSON as I feel its easier to read by a human if necessary, it can be used in both PHP and JavaScript with very little effort, and from what I've read, it might even be faster to decode (not sure about encoding, though).

Does anyone know of any pitfalls? Anyone have good benchmarks to show the performance benefits of either method?

Comment: Why not simply do something like:

```$array = array('foo' => 'bar');
file_put_contents('foo.php',  "<?php return ".var_export($array, true) . ";");```
.

and

.
```$array = file_get_contents('foo.php')));```


Of course, if this is for much larger data-volumes I'd probably go with.... CSV. So maybe not the sexiest - but it has been around longer than us both for a reason - and there's excellent support in PHP for partial or streamed access on really large datasets.

Answer (score 604, accepted):

Depends on your priorities.

If performance is your absolute driving characteristic, then by all means use the fastest one.  Just make sure you have a full understanding of the differences before you make a choice

- Unlike `serialize()` you need to add extra parameter to keep UTF-8 characters untouched: `json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`  (otherwise it converts UTF-8 characters to Unicode escape sequences).
- JSON will have no memory of what the object's original class was (they are always restored as instances of stdClass).
- You can't leverage `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` with JSON
- By default, only public properties are serialized with JSON. (in `PHP>=5.4` you can implement [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) to change this behavior).
- JSON is more portable

And there's probably a few other differences I can't think of at the moment.

A simple speed test to compare the two

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Make a big, honkin test array
// You may need to adjust this depth to avoid memory limit errors
$testArray = fillArray(0, 5);

// Time json encoding
$start = microtime(true);
json_encode($testArray);
$jsonTime = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "JSON encoded in $jsonTime seconds\n";

// Time serialization
$start = microtime(true);
serialize($testArray);
$serializeTime = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "PHP serialized in $serializeTime seconds\n";

// Compare them
if ($jsonTime < $serializeTime) {
    printf("json_encode() was roughly %01.2f%% faster than serialize()\n", ($serializeTime / $jsonTime - 1) * 100);
}
else if ($serializeTime < $jsonTime ) {
    printf("serialize() was roughly %01.2f%% faster than json_encode()\n", ($jsonTime / $serializeTime - 1) * 100);
} else {
    echo "Impossible!\n";
}

function fillArray( $depth, $max ) {
    static $seed;
    if (is_null($seed)) {
        $seed = array('a', 2, 'c', 4, 'e', 6, 'g', 8, 'i', 10);
    }
    if ($depth < $max) {
        $node = array();
        foreach ($seed as $key) {
            $node[$key] = fillArray($depth + 1, $max);
        }
        return $node;
    }
    return 'empty';
}
```

Comment: You make some great points. Fortunately, for my case, I'm storing simple arrays (of other arrays, ints, bools, and strings) no objects. If I were storing objects, IMO, serialize would be the way to go.

Comment: Too bad json_encode/json_decode is php 5.2 and above only. disgusts_uncover_akin_umbriel

Comment: "JSON converts UTF-8 characters to unicode escape sequences." No longer necessarily true: we now have `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.

Comment: Here we are almost 5 years later and I ran the tests again (just the `json_encode`) and it's averaging about 131% faster than serialize now. So, there must be some pretty nice improvements to that function in 5.4.x over 5.3.x. Specifically, I'm running 5.4.24 on CentOS 6. So, yay for JSON!!

Comment: JSON encoded in 0.0150480270386 seconds  
PHP serialized in 0.0309708118439 seconds  
json_encode() was roughly 105.81% faster than serialize()

Comment: in my case we encode once and decode a lot, so we benchmarked the json_decode vs unserialize and results was JSON dcoded in 0.06662392616272 seconds<br>
PHP unserialized in 0.093269109725952 seconds<br>
json_decode() was roughly 39.99% faster than unserialize()

Comment: Another difference is JSON is more readable and easier to modify.

Comment: Interesting: if you run this code on [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/qFKvT), the latest PHP7 development builds run serialize faster than json_encode: "serialize() was roughly 76.53% faster than json_encode()"

Comment: `PHP 5.5.21`: `json_encode` is 120-240% faster than `serialize`, while `unserialize` is 40-50% faster than `json_decode`.

Comment: Oh.. My.. God.. I just tested this code with symfony's [serializer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) -component and I have to say that I'm kinda speechless.. _"json_encode() was roughly 8,336.09% faster than serialize()"_  !!! O.O !!! I better change that to json_encode asap!

Comment: @KyleFarris how large was your array? I have an array with ~ 550 entries and unserialize/serialize was 200-400% faster then json_decode/json_encode.

Comment: Just to confirm on php7 JSON encoded in 0.0054829120635986 seconds
PHP serialized in 0.0049090385437012 seconds
serialize() was roughly 11.69% faster than json_encode()  on MacBook 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 16GB RAM

Comment: If no restriction, serialize work better with cyrillic symbols and quotes. Sending json_encoded data to DB and back breaks on quotes matching. Serialize does not. E.g., after recoding one system, the decision was to make all conversions uniform - i.e., json_encoded. The system broke -particularly, on filtering module that used data comparison of actual data from DB and stored keys that were json en-decoded (also retreived from DB). JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE help to some degree, but still could not workout quotes. Serialization just worked without stumbling.

Comment: 2017, PHP 7.1 and `serialize() was roughly 35.04% faster than json_encode()`

Comment: 2019, 7.1.27-1 `JSON encoded in 0.036638021469116 seconds PHP serialized in 0.027013063430786 seconds 
serialize() was roughly 35.63% faster than json_encode()`

Comment: 2020, PHP 7.4: `JSON encoded in 0.0064802169799805 seconds
PHP serialized in 0.0081288814544678 seconds
json_encode() was roughly 25.44% faster than serialize()`

Comment: Ok I know this is not really a part of this discussion, but when you use json_decode()  and you wanna have an array back you need to add the option JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY. 
Next to json_encode() the option JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE may help you to avoid character conversion problems in storage to your database and array to json scripts.
In all examples I did not see that remark. And in all the test this may cause timing differences in the comparison.

Comment: 2021, PHP 8.0.3 - Intel Core i7 5.0GHz - 16gb RAM `JSON encoded in 0.010940074920654 seconds PHP serialized in 0.007300853729248 seconds serialize() was roughly 49.85% faster than json_encode()`

Comment: I added encoding AND decoding, as well as serialize and unserialize. Serializing/unserializing was much faster.

Comment: oh boy seems like race between `serialize()` and `json_encode()` currently in php 8 `serialize()` is leading LOL

Comment: json_encode was on average about 10% faster but unserialize was about 250% faster than json_decode using php@7.4 on a m1.

Comment: running this code results each time in a different result, sometimes json is faster, other times serialize is faster, so strang ... why?

Comment: php 8.3: serialize() was roughly 8.43% faster than json_encode()

Answer (score 265):

**JSON** is simpler and faster than PHP's serialization format and should be used **unless**:

- You're storing deeply nested arrays:
  [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/json_decode): "This function will return false if the JSON encoded data is deeper than 127 elements."
- You're storing objects that need to be unserialized as the correct class
- You're interacting with old PHP versions that don't support json_decode

Comment: Great answer. Haha, 127 levels deep seems a bit insane; thankfully I'm only going like 2-3 at the most. Do you have any data to back up the fact that json_decode/json_encode is faster than unserialize/serialize?

Comment: I did test it a while ago and json came out faster - I don't have the data any more though.

Comment: @Kyle - I added a speed test to my answer.  On my server, json_encode() is averaging about 100% faster that serialize()

Comment: "5.3.0 Added the optional depth. The default recursion depth was increased from 128 to 512"

Comment: I would add one more item to the above list: json_encode() should not be used if your data might contain invalid UTF-8 byte sequences. It simply returns false for such data. Try for example: 

var_dump(json_encode("\xEF\xEF"));

Comment: Its  not true that it is faster in general. If you have a small array with about ~ 500 entries, then unserialize/serialize is actually 200-400% faster then json_decode/json_encode (PHP 5.6.19)

Comment: I have just done benchmarks in PHP 7.4 and serialise wins outright, check my answer below from what I have tested, although I am not very experienced, I may not have done it properly but with microtome(true) function serialise always takes less time and the strings are smaller too

Comment: I do not think JSON is better than serialize. serialize  can do everything of JSON, while JSON does less than serialize(the type information is lost in JSON). See https://myprogrammingnotes.com/serialize-vs-json_encode-unserialize-vs-json_decode.html

Answer (score 66):

I've written a blogpost about this subject: "[Cache a large array: JSON, serialize or var_export?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150906085640/http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/n618/news/view/34972/14863/cache-a-large-array-json-serialize-or-var_export.html)". In this post it is shown that serialize is the best choice for small to large sized arrays. For very large arrays (> 70MB) JSON is the better choice.

Comment: The link is not available any more.

Comment: Thanks, moose, I've updated the link. Although the article is almost 6 years old and might not be so accurate for current PHP versions.

Comment: I did some tests and made a simple function to test it, with big arrays (used function of Peter Bailey for those) the ``json_encode()`` is about **80% to 150%** faster (its really going up and down there) than ``serialize()``, with about 300 iterations. But when using the smaller arrays (``array("teams" => array(1 => array(4 arrays of players), 2 => array(4 arrays of players)))``), I did test with **750,000** iterations and ``serialize()`` is about **6% to 10%** faster in that case. My function takes the average times for all iterations and compares them. I might post it here as one of answers

Comment: if the datas are only used by PHP, var_export is my thing. Just need to be careful with possible syntax errors in the include thought.

Comment: blog no longer exists

Comment: @Gfra54: be careful with var_export, PHP's caching may not always give you back the most recent version of your file when you include (a "flash" message after a redirect stored in custom session file for example). See related answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/47914102/466498

Comment: Ok thanks @zmippie, good to know. The one second gap is not a problem for me tought.

Comment: seems to be based on the original article (for which the link is broken): https://blog.ijun.org/2010/09/cache-large-array-json-serialize-or.html

Comment: the original article from web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20171103000027/http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/n618/news/view/34972/14863/cache-a-large-array-json-serialize-or-var_export.html

Answer (score 61):

You might also be interested in https://github.com/phadej/igbinary - which provides a  different serialization 'engine' for PHP.

My random/arbitrary 'performance' figures, using PHP 5.3.5 on a 64bit platform show :

JSON :

- JSON encoded in 2.180496931076 seconds
- JSON decoded in 9.8368630409241 seconds
- serialized "String" size : 13993

Native PHP :

- PHP serialized   in 2.9125759601593 seconds
- PHP unserialized in 6.4348418712616 seconds
- serialized "String" size : 20769

Igbinary :

- *WIN* igbinary serialized    in 1.6099879741669 seconds
- *WIN* igbinrary unserialized in 4.7737920284271 seconds
- *WIN* serialized "String" Size : 4467

So, it's quicker to igbinary_serialize() and igbinary_unserialize() and uses less disk space.

I used the fillArray(0, 3) code as above, but made the array keys longer strings.

igbinary can store the same data types as PHP's native serialize can (So no problem with objects etc) and you can tell PHP5.3 to use it for session handling if you so wish.

See also http://ilia.ws/files/zendcon_2010_hidden_features.pdf - specifically slides 14/15/16

Comment: What about today? Now that we have PHP 7.*.* and even PHP 8.*.*? Should we give a try to igbinary? Thank you!

Answer (score 28):

Y just tested serialized and json encode and decode, plus the size it will take the string stored.

```
JSON encoded in 0.067085981369 seconds. Size (1277772)
PHP serialized in 0.12110209465 seconds. Size (1955548)
JSON decode in 0.22470498085 seconds
PHP serialized in 0.211947917938 seconds
json_encode() was roughly 80.52% faster than serialize()
unserialize() was roughly 6.02% faster than json_decode()
JSON string was roughly 53.04% smaller than Serialized string
```

We can conclude that JSON encodes faster and results a smaller string, but unserialize is faster to decode the string.

Comment: I don't know why people alwaye do performance test with so small dataset. Doing that you have all the overhead that add errors to your results. And if people are interested in performance it's probably because they have a very large dataset, because there is no point in gaining a micro sec once.

Comment: Quite often I iterate over many small datasets. With hundreds of small datasets, gaining 1mS for each one is still interesting.

Comment: @YannSagon Even with small datasets it makes sense to do a performence test. How should you know before the test if it is only about one micro sec?

Comment: I must have done something wrong then? Because I just did benchmark tests and Serialise and unserialise were faster, smaller strings

Answer (score 19):

If you are caching information that you will ultimately want to "include" at a later point in time, you may want to try using [var_export](https://www.php.net/var_export). That way you only take the hit in the "serialize" and not in the "unserialize".

Comment: This is most probably the fastest way possible. I wrote an example on the SO "PHP - *fast* serialize/unserialize": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545455/php-fast-serialize-unserialize/3369942#3369942

Answer (score 13):

I augmented the test to include unserialization performance. Here are the numbers I got.

```
Serialize

JSON encoded in 2.5738489627838 seconds
PHP serialized in 5.2861361503601 seconds
Serialize: json_encode() was roughly 105.38% faster than serialize()


Unserialize

JSON decode in 10.915472984314 seconds
PHP unserialized in 7.6223039627075 seconds
Unserialize: unserialize() was roughly 43.20% faster than json_decode()
```

So json seems to be faster for encoding but slow in decoding.  So it could depend upon your application and what you expect to do the most.

Answer (score 11):

Really nice topic and after reading the few answers, I want to share my experiments on the subject.

I got a use case where some "huge" table needs to be queried almost every time I talk to the database (don't ask why, just a fact). The database caching system isn't appropriate as it'll not cache the different requests, so I though about php caching systems.

I tried `apcu` but it didn't fit the needs, memory isn't enough reliable in this case. Next step was to cache into a file with serialization.

Table has 14355 entries with 18 columns, those are my tests and stats on reading the serialized cache:

### JSON:

As you all said, the major inconvenience with `json_encode`/`json_decode` is that it transforms everything to an `StdClass` instance (or Object). If you need to loop it, transforming it to an array is what you'll probably do, and yes it's increasing the transformation time

> average time: 780.2 ms; memory use: 41.5MB; cache file size: 3.8MB

### Msgpack

@hutch mentions [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/). Pretty website. Let's give it a try shall we?

> average time: 497 ms; memory use: 32MB; cache file size: 2.8MB

That's better, but requires a new extension; compiling sometimes afraid people...

### IgBinary

@GingerDog mentions [igbinary](https://github.com/phadej/igbinary). Note that I've set the `igbinary.compact_strings=Off`because I care more about reading performances than file size.

> average time: 411.4 ms; memory use: 36.75MB; cache file size: 3.3MB

Better than msg pack. Still, this one requires compiling too.

#### `serialize`/`unserialize`

> average time: 477.2 ms; memory use: 36.25MB; cache file size: 5.9MB

Better performances than JSON, the bigger the array is, slower `json_decode` is, but you already new that.

Those external extensions are narrowing down the file size and seems great on paper. Numbers don't lie*. What's the point of compiling an extension if you get almost the same results that you'd have with a standard PHP function?

We can also deduce that depending on your needs, you will choose something different than someone else:

- IgBinary is really nice and performs better than MsgPack
- Msgpack is better at compressing your datas (note that I didn't tried the igbinary
  compact.string option).
- Don't want to compile? Use standards.

That's it, another serialization methods comparison to help you choose the one!

*Tested with PHPUnit 3.7.31, php 5.5.10 - only decoding with a standard hardrive and old dual core CPU - average numbers on 10 same use case tests, your stats might be different

Comment: Why not to pass flag to json_decode to force returning arrays?

Comment: Because it's slow. I didn't test this but I think that simply forcing the type change from php is faster.

Comment: I just know that creating arrays much faster than objects in php.

Comment: So you're talking about `json_decode($object, true)`, basically it'll do the same as `(array) json_decode($object)` but recursively so that would be the same behavior and it'll have a significant cost in both cases. Note that I haven't tested performance diffs between `StdClass` and `array` but that's not really the point here.

Comment: I'm sure it's another cost because it's done on lower level without objects.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is late but the answers are pretty old, I thought my benchmarks might help as I have just tested in PHP 7.4

Serialize/Unserialize is much faster than JSON, takes less memory and space, and wins outright in PHP 7.4 but I am not sure my test is the most efficient or the best,

I have basically created a PHP file which returns an array which I encoded, serialised, then decoded and unserialised.

```
$array = include __DIR__.'/../tests/data/dao/testfiles/testArray.php';

//JSON ENCODE
$json_encode_memory_start = memory_get_usage();
$json_encode_time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
    $encoded = json_encode($array);
}

$json_encode_time_end = microtime(true);
$json_encode_memory_end = memory_get_usage();
$json_encode_time = $json_encode_time_end - $json_encode_time_start;
$json_encode_memory = 
$json_encode_memory_end - $json_encode_memory_start;


//SERIALIZE
$serialize_memory_start = memory_get_usage();
$serialize_time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
    $serialized = serialize($array);
}

$serialize_time_end = microtime(true);
$serialize_memory_end = memory_get_usage();
$serialize_time = $serialize_time_end - $serialize_time_start;
$serialize_memory = $serialize_memory_end - $serialize_memory_start;


//Write to file time:
$fpc_memory_start = memory_get_usage();
$fpc_time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
    $fpc_bytes = 
    file_put_contents(
        __DIR__.'/../tests/data/dao/testOneBigFile',
        '<?php return '.var_export($array,true).' ?>;'
    );
}

$fpc_time_end = microtime(true);
$fpc_memory_end = memory_get_usage();
$fpc_time = $fpc_time_end - $fpc_time_start;
$fpc_memory = $fpc_memory_end - $fpc_memory_start;


//JSON DECODE
$json_decode_memory_start = memory_get_usage();
$json_decode_time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
    $decoded = json_encode($encoded);
}

$json_decode_time_end = microtime(true);
$json_decode_memory_end = memory_get_usage();
$json_decode_time = $json_decode_time_end - $json_decode_time_start;
$json_decode_memory = 
$json_decode_memory_end - $json_decode_memory_start;


//UNSERIALIZE
$unserialize_memory_start = memory_get_usage();
$unserialize_time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
    $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
}

$unserialize_time_end = microtime(true);
$unserialize_memory_end = memory_get_usage();
$unserialize_time = $unserialize_time_end - $unserialize_time_start;
$unserialize_memory = 
$unserialize_memory_end - $unserialize_memory_start;


//GET FROM VAR EXPORT:
$var_export_memory_start = memory_get_usage();
$var_export_time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < 20000; $i++) { 
    $array = include __DIR__.'/../tests/data/dao/testOneBigFile';
}

$var_export_time_end = microtime(true);
$var_export_memory_end = memory_get_usage();
$var_export_time = $var_export_time_end - $var_export_time_start;
$var_export_memory = $var_export_memory_end - $var_export_memory_start;
```

Results:

Var Export length: 11447
Serialized length: 11541
Json encoded length: 11895
file put contents Bytes: 11464

Json Encode Time: 1.9197590351105
Serialize Time: 0.160325050354
FPC Time: 6.2793469429016

Json Encode Memory: 12288
Serialize Memory: 12288
FPC Memory: 0

JSON Decoded time: 1.7493588924408
UnSerialize Time: 0.19309520721436
Var Export and Include: 3.1974139213562

JSON Decoded memory: 16384
UnSerialize Memory: 14360
Var Export and Include: 192

Answer (score 8):

Seems like serialize is the one I'm going to use for 2 reasons:

- Someone pointed out that unserialize is faster than json_decode and a 'read' case sounds more probable than a 'write' case.
- I've had trouble with json_encode when having strings with invalid UTF-8 characters. When that happens the string ends up being empty causing loss of information.

Answer (score 6):

I've tested this very thoroughly on a fairly complex, mildly nested multi-hash with all kinds of data in it (string, NULL, integers), and serialize/unserialize ended up much faster than json_encode/json_decode.

The only advantage json have in my tests was it's smaller 'packed' size.

These are done under PHP 5.3.3, let me know if you want more details.

Here are tests results then the code to produce them. I can't provide the test data since it'd reveal information that I can't let go out in the wild.

```
JSON encoded in 2.23700618744 seconds
PHP serialized in 1.3434419632 seconds
JSON decoded in 4.0405561924 seconds
PHP unserialized in 1.39393305779 seconds

serialized size : 14549
json_encode size : 11520
serialize() was roughly 66.51% faster than json_encode()
unserialize() was roughly 189.87% faster than json_decode()
json_encode() string was roughly 26.29% smaller than serialize()

//  Time json encoding
$start = microtime( true );
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    json_encode( $test );
}
$jsonTime = microtime( true ) - $start;
echo "JSON encoded in $jsonTime seconds<br>";

//  Time serialization
$start = microtime( true );
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    serialize( $test );
}
$serializeTime = microtime( true ) - $start;
echo "PHP serialized in $serializeTime seconds<br>";

//  Time json decoding
$test2 = json_encode( $test );
$start = microtime( true );
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    json_decode( $test2 );
}
$jsonDecodeTime = microtime( true ) - $start;
echo "JSON decoded in $jsonDecodeTime seconds<br>";

//  Time deserialization
$test2 = serialize( $test );
$start = microtime( true );
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    unserialize( $test2 );
}
$unserializeTime = microtime( true ) - $start;
echo "PHP unserialized in $unserializeTime seconds<br>";

$jsonSize = strlen(json_encode( $test ));
$phpSize = strlen(serialize( $test ));

echo "<p>serialized size : " . strlen(serialize( $test )) . "<br>";
echo "json_encode size : " . strlen(json_encode( $test )) . "<br></p>";

//  Compare them
if ( $jsonTime < $serializeTime )
{
    echo "json_encode() was roughly " . number_format( ($serializeTime / $jsonTime - 1 ) * 100, 2 ) . "% faster than serialize()";
}
else if ( $serializeTime < $jsonTime )
{
    echo "serialize() was roughly " . number_format( ($jsonTime / $serializeTime - 1 ) * 100, 2 ) . "% faster than json_encode()";
} else {
    echo 'Unpossible!';
}
    echo '<BR>';

//  Compare them
if ( $jsonDecodeTime < $unserializeTime )
{
    echo "json_decode() was roughly " . number_format( ($unserializeTime / $jsonDecodeTime - 1 ) * 100, 2 ) . "% faster than unserialize()";
}
else if ( $unserializeTime < $jsonDecodeTime )
{
    echo "unserialize() was roughly " . number_format( ($jsonDecodeTime / $unserializeTime - 1 ) * 100, 2 ) . "% faster than json_decode()";
} else {
    echo 'Unpossible!';
}
    echo '<BR>';
//  Compare them
if ( $jsonSize < $phpSize )
{
    echo "json_encode() string was roughly " . number_format( ($phpSize / $jsonSize - 1 ) * 100, 2 ) . "% smaller than serialize()";
}
else if ( $phpSize < $jsonSize )
{
    echo "serialize() string was roughly " . number_format( ($jsonSize / $phpSize - 1 ) * 100, 2 ) . "% smaller than json_encode()";
} else {
    echo 'Unpossible!';
}
```

Comment: I have just performed a similar test with PHP 5.4.12 and found similar results: {un,}serialize is faster. My data is hashes nested 3 levels deep (900k serialized).

Answer (score 6):

I made a small benchmark as well. My results were the same. But I need the decode performance. Where I noticed, like a few people above said as well, `unserialize` is faster than `json_decode`. `unserialize` takes roughly 60-70% of the `json_decode` time. So the conclusion is fairly simple:
When you need performance in encoding, use `json_encode`, when you need performance when decoding, use `unserialize`. Because you can not merge the two functions you have to make a choise where you need more performance.

My benchmark in pseudo:

- Define array $arr with a few random keys and values
- for x < 100; x++; serialize and json_encode a array_rand of $arr
- for y < 1000; y++; json_decode the json encoded string - calc time
- for y < 1000; y++; unserialize the serialized string - calc time
- echo the result which was faster

On avarage: unserialize won 96 times over 4 times the json_decode. With an avarage of roughly 1.5ms over 2.5ms.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the results here (sorry for the hack putting the PHP code in the JS code box):

**http://jsfiddle.net/newms87/h3b0a0ha/embedded/result/**

**RESULTS: `serialize()` and `unserialize()` are both significantly faster in PHP 5.4 on arrays of varying size.**

I made a test script on real world data for comparing json_encode vs serialize and json_decode vs unserialize. The test was run on the caching system of an in production e-commerce site. It simply takes the data already in the cache, and tests the times to encode / decode (or serialize / unserialize) all the data and I put it in an easy to see table.

I ran this on PHP 5.4 shared hosting server.

The results were very conclusive that for these large to small data sets serialize and unserialize were the clear winners. In particular for my use case, the json_decode and unserialize are the most important for the caching system. Unserialize was almost an ubiquitous winner here. It was typically 2 to 4 times (sometimes 6 or 7 times) as fast as json_decode.

It is interesting to note the difference in results from @peter-bailey.

Here is the PHP code used to generate the results:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function _count_depth($array)
{
    $count     = 0;
    $max_depth = 0;
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (is_array($a)) {
            list($cnt, $depth) = _count_depth($a);
            $count += $cnt;
            $max_depth = max($max_depth, $depth);
        } else {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    return array(
        $count,
        $max_depth + 1,
    );
}

function run_test($file)
{
    $memory     = memory_get_usage();
    $test_array = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
    $memory     = round((memory_get_usage() - $memory) / 1024, 2);

    if (empty($test_array) || !is_array($test_array)) {
        return;
    }

    list($count, $depth) = _count_depth($test_array);

    //JSON encode test
    $start            = microtime(true);
    $json_encoded     = json_encode($test_array);
    $json_encode_time = microtime(true) - $start;

    //JSON decode test
    $start = microtime(true);
    json_decode($json_encoded);
    $json_decode_time = microtime(true) - $start;

    //serialize test
    $start          = microtime(true);
    $serialized     = serialize($test_array);
    $serialize_time = microtime(true) - $start;

    //unserialize test
    $start = microtime(true);
    unserialize($serialized);
    $unserialize_time = microtime(true) - $start;

    return array(
        'Name'                   => basename($file),
        'json_encode() Time (s)' => $json_encode_time,
        'json_decode() Time (s)' => $json_decode_time,
        'serialize() Time (s)'   => $serialize_time,
        'unserialize() Time (s)' => $unserialize_time,
        'Elements'               => $count,
        'Memory (KB)'            => $memory,
        'Max Depth'              => $depth,
        'json_encode() Win'      => ($json_encode_time > 0 && $json_encode_time < $serialize_time) ? number_format(($serialize_time / $json_encode_time - 1) * 100, 2) : '',
        'serialize() Win'        => ($serialize_time > 0 && $serialize_time < $json_encode_time) ? number_format(($json_encode_time / $serialize_time - 1) * 100, 2) : '',
        'json_decode() Win'      => ($json_decode_time > 0 && $json_decode_time < $serialize_time) ? number_format(($serialize_time / $json_decode_time - 1) * 100, 2) : '',
        'unserialize() Win'      => ($unserialize_time > 0 && $unserialize_time < $json_decode_time) ? number_format(($json_decode_time / $unserialize_time - 1) * 100, 2) : '',
    );
}

$files = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/system/cache/*');

$data = array();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (is_file($file)) {
        $result = run_test($file);

        if ($result) {
            $data[] = $result;
        }
    }
}

uasort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['Memory (KB)'] < $b['Memory (KB)'];
});

$fields = array_keys($data[0]);
?>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($fields as $f) { ?>
            <td style="text-align: center; border:1px solid black;padding: 4px 8px;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.1em"><?= $f; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($data as $d) { ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($d as $key => $value) { ?>
                <?php $is_win = strpos($key, 'Win'); ?>
                <?php $color = ($is_win && $value) ? 'color: green;font-weight:bold;' : ''; ?>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 3px 6px; border: 1px solid gray; <?= $color; ?>"><?= $value . (($is_win && $value) ? '%' : ''); ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I changed the script to do some more benchmarking (and also do 1000 runs instead of just 1):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Make a big, honkin test array
// You may need to adjust this depth to avoid memory limit errors
$testArray = fillArray(0, 5);

$totalJsonTime = 0;
$totalSerializeTime = 0;
$totalJsonWins = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    // Time json encoding
    $start = microtime(true);
    $json = json_encode($testArray);
    $jsonTime = microtime(true) - $start;
    $totalJsonTime += $jsonTime;

    // Time serialization
    $start = microtime(true);
    $serial = serialize($testArray);
    $serializeTime = microtime(true) - $start;
    $totalSerializeTime += $serializeTime;

    if ($jsonTime < $serializeTime) {
        $totalJsonWins++;
    }
}

$totalSerializeWins = 1000 - $totalJsonWins;

// Compare them
if ($totalJsonTime < $totalSerializeTime) {
    printf("json_encode() (wins: $totalJsonWins) was roughly %01.2f%% faster than serialize()\n", ($totalSerializeTime / $totalJsonTime - 1) * 100);
} else {
    printf("serialize() (wins: $totalSerializeWins) was roughly %01.2f%% faster than json_encode()\n", ($totalJsonTime / $totalSerializeTime - 1) * 100);
}

$totalJsonTime = 0;
$totalJson2Time = 0;
$totalSerializeTime = 0;
$totalJsonWins = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    // Time json decoding
    $start = microtime(true);
    $orig = json_decode($json, true);
    $jsonTime = microtime(true) - $start;
    $totalJsonTime += $jsonTime;

    $start = microtime(true);
    $origObj = json_decode($json);
    $jsonTime2 = microtime(true) - $start;
    $totalJson2Time += $jsonTime2;

    // Time serialization
    $start = microtime(true);
    $unserial = unserialize($serial);
    $serializeTime = microtime(true) - $start;
    $totalSerializeTime += $serializeTime;

    if ($jsonTime < $serializeTime) {
        $totalJsonWins++;
    }
}

$totalSerializeWins = 1000 - $totalJsonWins;


// Compare them
if ($totalJsonTime < $totalSerializeTime) {
    printf("json_decode() was roughly %01.2f%% faster than unserialize()\n", ($totalSerializeTime / $totalJsonTime - 1) * 100);
} else {
    printf("unserialize() (wins: $totalSerializeWins) was roughly %01.2f%% faster than json_decode()\n", ($totalJsonTime / $totalSerializeTime - 1) * 100);
}

// Compare them
if ($totalJson2Time < $totalSerializeTime) {
    printf("json_decode() was roughly %01.2f%% faster than unserialize()\n", ($totalSerializeTime / $totalJson2Time - 1) * 100);
} else {
    printf("unserialize() (wins: $totalSerializeWins) was roughly %01.2f%% faster than array json_decode()\n", ($totalJson2Time / $totalSerializeTime - 1) * 100);
}

function fillArray( $depth, $max ) {
    static $seed;
    if (is_null($seed)) {
        $seed = array('a', 2, 'c', 4, 'e', 6, 'g', 8, 'i', 10);
    }
    if ($depth < $max) {
        $node = array();
        foreach ($seed as $key) {
            $node[$key] = fillArray($depth + 1, $max);
        }
        return $node;
    }
    return 'empty';
}
```

I used this build of PHP 7:

> PHP 7.0.14 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 19:13:23) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.14, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

And my results were:

> serialize() (wins: 999) was roughly 10.98% faster than json_encode()
>   unserialize() (wins: 987) was roughly 33.26% faster than json_decode()
>   unserialize() (wins: 987) was roughly 48.35% faster than array
>   json_decode()

So **clearly**, serialize/unserialize is the **fastest** method, while json_encode/decode is the **most portable.**

If you consider a scenario where you read/write serialized data 10x or more often than you need to send to or receive from a non-PHP system, you are STILL better off to use serialize/unserialize and have it json_encode or json_decode prior to serialization in terms of time.

Comment: $ php8.1 -f test.php
serialize() (wins: 992) was roughly 20.57% faster than json_encode()
unserialize() (wins: 999) was roughly 110.41% faster than json_decode()
unserialize() (wins: 999) was roughly 138.71% faster than array json_decode()

Comment: $ php7.4 -f test.php
serialize() (wins: 970) was roughly 7.30% faster than json_encode()
unserialize() (wins: 1000) was roughly 164.96% faster than json_decode()
unserialize() (wins: 1000) was roughly 177.39% faster than array json_decode()

Answer (score 2):

Before you make your final decision, be aware that the JSON format is not safe for associative arrays - `json_decode()` will return them as objects instead:

```
$config = array(
    'Frodo'   => 'hobbit',
    'Gimli'   => 'dwarf',
    'Gandalf' => 'wizard',
    );
print_r($config);
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($config)));
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [Frodo] => hobbit
    [Gimli] => dwarf
    [Gandalf] => wizard
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Frodo] => hobbit
    [Gimli] => dwarf
    [Gandalf] => wizard
)
```

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I mean, it *is* Javascript **object** notation afterall! Thankfully, if you *know* that what you encoded using `json_encode` was an associative array, you can easily force it back into an array like so: `$json = json_encode($some_assoc_array); $back_to_array = (array)json_decode($json);` Also it's good to note that you can access objects the same way as arrays in PHP so in a typical scenario, one wouldn't even know the difference. Good point though!

Comment: @toomuchphp, sorry but you are wrong. There is a second parameter for json_decode 'bool $assoc = false' that makes json_decode produce an array. @KyleFarris, this should also be faster than using the typecast to array.

Comment: the answer is not correct. when using true as second parameter of function, json_decode() will return associative arrays instead of objects.

Answer (score 1):

just an fyi -- if you want to serialize your data to something easy to read and understand like JSON but with more compression and higher performance, you should check out [messagepack.](http://msgpack.org/)

Comment: if it's just an fyi, you'd better put it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

THX - for this benchmark code:

My results on array I use for configuration are as fallows:
JSON encoded in 0.0031511783599854 seconds
PHP serialized in 0.0037961006164551 seconds
`json_encode()` was roughly 20.47% faster than `serialize()`
JSON encoded in 0.0070841312408447 seconds
PHP serialized in 0.0035839080810547 seconds
`unserialize()` was roughly 97.66% faster than `json_encode()`

So - test it on your own data.

Comment: You mean json_decode() in "unserialize() was roughly 97.66% faster than json_encode()", yes?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is better if you want to backup Data and restore it on a different machine or via FTP.

For example with serialize if you store data on a Windows server, download it via FTP and restore it on a Linux one it could not work any more due to the charachter re-encoding, because serialize stores the length of the strings and in the Unicode > UTF-8 transcoding some 1 byte charachter could became 2 bytes long making the algorithm crash.

Answer (score 0):

If to summ up what people say here, json_decode/encode seems faster than serialize/unserialize BUT
If you do var_dump the type of the serialized object is changed.
If for some reason you want to keep the type, go with serialize!

(try for example stdClass vs array)

serialize/unserialize:

```
Array cache:
array (size=2)
  'a' => string '1' (length=1)
  'b' => int 2
Object cache:
object(stdClass)[8]
  public 'field1' => int 123
This cache:
object(Controller\Test)[8]
  protected 'view' =>
```

json encode/decode

```
Array cache:
object(stdClass)[7]
  public 'a' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'b' => int 2
Object cache:
object(stdClass)[8]
  public 'field1' => int 123
This cache:
object(stdClass)[8]
```

As you can see the json_encode/decode converts all to stdClass, which is not that good, object info lost... So decide based on needs, especially if it is not only arrays...

Comment: Just a note: Most other answers say that serialize/unserialize is faster.

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest you to use Super Cache, which is a file cache mechanism which won't use `json_encode` or `serialize`. It is simple to use and really fast compared to other PHP Cache mechanism.

https://packagist.org/packages/smart-php/super-cache

Ex:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use SuperCache\SuperCache as sCache;

//Saving cache value with a key
// sCache::cache('<key>')->set('<value>');
sCache::cache('myKey')->set('Key_value');

//Retrieving cache value with a key
echo sCache::cache('myKey')->get();
?>
```

Comment: -1. While it might be a better solution, no part of this answer actually answers the OP's question. In future, perhaps try answering the question but leaving a suggestion at the bottom that an alternative solution might be worth investigation.