# What is more efficient to use Json_encode the data or to serialize the data and store in database?

Tags: php, json, serialization

Just came across serialize() in php. Many databases  store the data in serialized form so curious to know what is more usefun json or serialize and why?

```
 Json Data->["Math","Language","Science","History"]
 serialized Data->a:4:{i:0;s:4:"Math";i:1;s:8:"Language";i:2;s:7:"Science";i:3;s:7:"History";}
```

Comment: Not everything can be converted to JSON. If you want to retain actual object instances, you'll have to use `serialize`. If all you want to store is simple data types (i.e. `array`s & `stdClass`es), you'll be fine with `json_encode`.

Comment: Why not `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` instead ?

Comment: Shankar. I beleive the point in serializing or json is for speed not to encrypt. Base64 is both bulky, slow, but it doesn't speed anything up.

Comment: True Andrew. Why I suggested that is.. say if the OP is storing an image , In that case `json_encode()` fails.

Comment: Is serialize capable of storing any kind of OP?

Answer (score 4):

Serialize() is a native PHP method of storing data in text strings. It can even store objects. And it has a special notation for objects. JSON, it its turn, is a JavaScript's Object Notation. Basically, same thing. But they are used in different domains.

JSON is usually used for online communication - sending data to/from AJAX scripts, numerous API's, etc. It appeared to be much lighter and readable than XML, thus it competes with it for the most commonly used data transfer standard for APIs. It is also widely used in config files, say, for **Composter** - where readability is one of the top requirements.
Visual readability and easy structure makes JSON the best way to communicate **between different**  platforms and programming languages. This, last phrase is important.

PHP Serializing is used in cases where you save data in PHP **and** you restore data back in PHP as well. Say, you can save arrays, or $user object into a PHP session, and then restore them back. Or store a multi-dimensional array in a MySQL field, and then restore it exactly as it was in an $array variable. In most cases Serialized data is not much shorter/lighter than JSON and doesn't usually take less space - it makes it lose readability though. But there are quite powerful tricks with it PHP has - it preserves data types, classes names, visibility options, etc. Also refer to `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` magic class methods allowing you to save objects on the fly and create special constructors to revive them back, again, on the fly.

In your particular case, if you store data in MySQL database with PHP, and then read it back to PHP - then PHP serialization would be the best way to use. Unless you want to access this data with other languages, or edit manually/visually.

Comment: "Serialized data is much shorter/lighter than JSON and takes less space" - given the asker's example, I find it hand to believe. Can you provide an example of when it is the case?

Comment: Jan Dvorak: It depends on what exactly you want to save. Basically, there won't be any sufficient gain in size, and storing simple array of numbers or strings - JSON beats serialize(). But! With serialize() you will retain the types! Serialize() saves data types for correct restoring, classes names, and it even saves the visibility attributes for properties - whether they were public or private. That is worth quite a lot.

Comment: Then _that_ should be  mentioned in the answer, not a size improvement  you don't even consider significant or have an example of. I fully agree that "retains object types" is a significant benefit.

Comment: Ah, I can see you've added "not" in "is not much shorter". I assume you also meant "does not take much less space"?

Comment: Jan - yes, sorry. As for me, I use serialization with objects (__sleep and __wakeup) ALOT - it allows you to do true Magic, if you give it a thought. 

And I use JSON in my config files, all AJAX requests, with 3-rd party APIs, in my own API, and for storing complex data in database fields for visual editing (like, some "settings" array in one MySQL field). So, practically, both have much use. Depending on the situation.

Comment: uh, no. serialization has multibyte character issues where the lengths stored don't actually match the lengths read, so when you unserialize it, your object doesn't actually get created again. "best". give me a break.

Answer (score 1):

to complete Oleg's answer I would like to suggest you to visit this link with objetive comparisons between json_encode and serialize PHP methods:

http://www.shozab.com/php-serialization-vs-json-encoding-for-an-array

It shows how serialize is usually slower but not recommended for all situations.

And finally here you have another discussion with many contributions in stackoverflow:

[Serialize or json in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574728/serialize-or-json-in-php)

Hope it will be interesting for you.