# Uses of serialize() in php

Tags: php

Uses of serialize() in php.its advantages and dis advantages

Comment: Smells like "I just heard of this function, I have no idea what it's for but I want to use it anyway so I'm gonna ask SO"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574728/serialize-or-json-in-php

Comment: Eating tomatoes. it's advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: *(related)* [What is PHP `serialize()` for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180602/what-is-php-serialize-for)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Advantages:

Turns objects into a string

Disadvantages:

Turns objects into a string

Comment: @Bolt I disagree. This is not an answer, It just mocks the OP's original poor question. I don't see why it should be upvoted when the OP gets close- and downvoted.

Comment: @Gordon Well seems the moral is: A bad question deserves a bad answer:) And this thread deserves to be closed, both OP's question and the answers here were below SO standard

Comment: @Sondre no, it doesn't. It deserves no answer at all or a comment at worst. I understand the urge to provide an snide remark like this, but providing it as an answer is repwhoring. I agree that the Q should be closed (which is why I closevoted)

Comment: @gordon Ye I totally agree with you, was merly pointing out that people seems to enjoy voting up answers making fun of a poorly asked OP. People just see it as a safe and easy way to get some rep without really contributing at all

Comment: @Gordon:  I didn't upvote. I happen to also be the first close voter.

Answer (score 6):

**Disadvantages**

- Resources are not serialized, and have to be manually recreated when unserialized
- [Implementation has a number of open bugs](http://bugs.php.net/search.php?search_for=unserialize&boolean=0&limit=30&order_by=&direction=DESC&cmd=display&status=Open&bug_type=All&php_os=&phpver=&cve_id=&assign=&author_email=&bug_age=0&bug_updated=0)

**Advantages**

PHP provides magic methods allowing you to handle this disadvantage

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any disadvantage of serialization.

Advantage is that you can serialize objects and arrays and save them (for example in database). Later, you can get objects back (unserialize) in the exactly same state, in which they were saved.

Comment: Sample disadvantages: speed, and same-state-but-not-really-same-state (database connections, anyone?)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 1):

It turns the object or array passed to it as the first (and only) argument to a string. This function is useful for storing objects in a database or file, for example. To turn the string back into an object or array, use unserialize().
Also look at the documentation of the function at:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score -1):

Only disadvantage is with utf8 encoding!

Comment: Can you explain? I've never had any problems with UTF-8 values and serialization... only with faulty storage of serialized objects that contain UTF-8 values

Comment: but i did had, so thats why i used json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize -JSON converts UTF-8 characters to unicode escape sequences. serialize() does not.

Comment: @Eddsstudio - what was your problem?

Comment: I needed to cache some arrays into files, and had some problems with symbols in latvian.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem if all you're doing is reading and writing those files... just don't edit them manually unless it's with an editor that will treat them as UTF-8.