# My PHP code serializes, but doesn't unserialize

Tags: php, serialization

THis this my code .

```
$data = array(
        '24 Jan|8:30' => '12.6',
        '22 Feb|8:30' => '250',
        '11 Mar|8:10' => '0',
        '31 Apr|23:30' => '7',
        '32 Apr|23:30' => '80',
        '33 Apr|23:30' => '67',
        '34 r|23:30' => '45',
        '35 Ap|23:30' => '66',
        '34 Lr|23:30' => '23',
        '3 Apr|23:30' => '23'
    );

    //echo serialize($data);
    $x = unserialize('a:10:{s:12:"24 Jan|8:30 ";s:4:"12.6";s:12:"22 Feb|8:30 ";s:3:"250";s:12:"11 Mar|8:10 ";s:1:"0";s:12:"31 Apr|23:30";s:1:"7";s:12:"32 Apr|23:30";s:2:"80";s:12:"33 Apr|23:30";s:2:"67";s:12:"34 r|23:30 ";s:2:"45";s:12:"35 Ap|23:30 ";s:2:"66";s:12:"34 Lr|23:30 ";s:2:"23";s:12:"3 Apr|23:30 ";s:2:"23";}');
    var_dump($x);
```

Not work in unserialize function.
Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize

Answer (score 4):

The serialized representation of $data and the string you are trying to unserialize differ.

http://codepad.viper-7.com/3zlk1a

At offset 199 you see

```
s:12:"34 r|23:30 "
```

but the string (`s`) isn't 12 characters long (thats what `s:12:` mean). I guess something modified the serialized string directly. Just don't do it :) Always unserialize and work with the structured values.

Answer (score 4):

```
'a:10:{s:12:"24 Jan|8:30 ";s:4:"12.6";s:12:"22 Feb|8:30 ";s:3:"250";s:12:"11 Mar|8:10 ";s:1:"0";s:12:"31 Apr|23:30";s:1:"7";s:12:"32 Apr|23:30";s:2:"80";s:12:"33 Apr|23:30";s:2:"67";s:12:"34 r|23:30 ";s:2:"45";s:12:"35 Ap|23:30 ";s:2:"66";s:12:"34 Lr|23:30 ";s:2:"23";s:12:"3 Apr|23:30 ";s:2:"23";}'
```

...is not a valid serialization. Specifically, the `s:12:"34 r|23:30 ";` segment indicates that the string `34 r|23:30` contains 12 characters, which it does not.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $a = serialize($data);
 $x = unserialize($a);
```