# MYSQL dont store entire variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When I echo a variable it gave me a great looking list but when I update mysql database it only add the last row in the list I read that there is a problem with array and foreach with mysql.

```
  foreach ($array["product"] as $list)
            {
            $ok = ''.$list[0].'';
            $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE product SET desc='$ok' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
                      }
            }
```

Is there an easy way to put my list in mysql whitout having to serialize I read its not the best thing to do and I am not familiar with that.

Thanks!

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. This will also help prevent any quoting headaches you might be running into.

Comment: `UPDATE` queries don't generally "put in mysql".

Comment: Yeah you right I already insert information I want to update the row

Comment: how(when  you change the $id ???

Comment: @Pierre-luc yeah, just making sure to cover bases; and scaisEdge beat me to my next question.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply i have no trouble update the row but the issue is it only save the last line in my list i need all line. sometime my list can be big like 50 line and right now I only manage to save the last. When i echo it show all of them something wrong.

Comment: It appears you are updating the same record in the database every iteration. `WHERE id='$id'` never changes.

Comment: Yah thats what I want :) I just need the complete list not just the last row :) the $list[0] is my issue here I think And I am really block with that.

Comment: Without changing the $id, you will just be overwriting the contents of `desc` with the last $ok. Were you wanting to append instead?

Comment: No I want to overwrite for now.

Comment: Great i manage to serialize and add all data using the example of "tipico" here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize

Comment: After testing i dont recommand serialize because the loading time of the page will increase a lot.