# Codeigniter permisson for new page PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a new page in a PHP codeigniter project.

With specific users, (not admin) i get the auth/deny when clicking on a link.

I found the string which generates the permissions for the users, but i dont know how to analyze.

I have 4 page: tenders, phonebook, partners, and the new is tendersnew.

The string in the database:

```
a:1:{s:3:"uri";a:4:{i:0;s:6:"/main/";i:1;s:11:"/phonebook/";i:2;s:9:"/tenders/";i:3;s:10:"/partners/";}}
```

now i have to add the tendersnew link, but i dont know what are theese numbers.

This is my first codeigniter project, i have to supplement with 1-2 features..

thanks!

Comment: I think we are going to need a lot more details to help.  What codeigniter version are you using?  Is this an old project or a new one?  What database/table did you get that string out of?  What exactly do you mean by "pages"?  Routes, for instance, aren't kept in the database at all.  You may want to read up on how to ask a question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Also, as for those numbers, that is simply how PHP serializes an array.  As a result those numbers represent PHP details, and are not of interest to you at all.

Comment: Some more on PHP serialize: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize

Comment: the string is from permissions table, data column. this is an old project. codeigniter 2.1.0. i have 3 controllers/models/views. i am adding now one more, named tendersnew.

Comment: thank you for the link, i think i got it

Comment: Codeigniter 2 is pretty old.  If you have any choice in the matter migrating to Codeigniter 3 would be a good idea.  Exactly what module are you using here?  Codeigniter 3 doesn't have a permissions module, so normally people would download and install (or build) their own.  I've never used codeigniter 2 so I don't know if it had its own which was removed in CI 3 or if someone installed a thirdparty module which you need to figure out how to use.  Either way, more details are going to be needed here, and I think you need to figure out what you actually have first.