# How to save array of objects to mysql database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am using vue with laravel. I am trying to save array of objects but not able to do it though i am able to save single object. Here is my code
App.vue

```
// Not working
saveData(){
  this.axios.post('/addperson', **this.rows**).then((response) => {
    console.log("WOW");
  })
}

//working
    saveData(){
      this.axios.post('/addperson', **this.rows[0]**).then((response) => {
        console.log("WOW");
      })
    }
```

Here is controller code where i am getting error when i pass array.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\OrderPerson;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
  public function create(Request $request){

      $person = new Person([
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'age' => $request->get('age'),
        'user_id' =>$request->get('user_id')''
      ]);

      $person->save();
    return response()->json('Successfully added');
  }
}
```

Can any body help me to save the array?

Comment: you can use serialise method to store in db

Comment: @iCoders, can you give me reference link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all assign all the `this.rows` to a data set then push it to the axios call something like this:

```
saveData(){
    const postData = {
            data: this.rows
        }
  this.axios.post('/addperson', postData).then((response) => {
    console.log("WOW");
  })
}
```

Now in `laravel` controller you can use `foreach` to use this data set.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\OrderPerson;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
  public function create(Request $request){

    foreach($request->data as $data)
    {
        $container = new Person([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'age' => $data['age'],
            'user_id' => $data['user_id']
          ]);

        $container->save();
    }

    return response()->json('Successfully added');
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.