# I have value in my wp_postmeta table like a:1:{i:0;s:1:"5";}.....I need to get the last value.that is the value inside the " ".in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on Wordpress. I use custom fields and one of the field category contains field type as `taxonomy`.

While inserting,the `postmeta` table contains this JSON value: `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"5";}`.

I need to get the value inside the `" "`.That is `5`.

Comment: That is not valid JSON

Comment: That is actually PHP's [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) data format; see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8641889/1427878 Elvin85 is of course correct though, that you should stick to the functionality WP provides around this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use native get_post_meta function which unserializes data itself:

```
echo get_post_meta(POST_ID_HERE,'post_meta_key_name_here',true)[0];
```

or this

```
$value=get_post_meta(POST_ID_HERE,'post_meta_key_name_here',true);
echo $value[0];
```