# Does it count as JSON?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, joomla

Working with Joomla and Wordpress CMSs, I found weird rows in both of them, for example WordPress has a row in `wp_options` table called `wp_user_roles` which filled with `a:8:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator"...` which i don't call it JSON but obviously its something very similar, I just want to know what it is, also I couldn't find any function to parse it in php easily.

Comment: Function `unserialize`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not JSON, but serialized

[serialize](http://php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php)
[unserialize](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php)

As commented by [Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren), in [this Question (How to use php serialize() and unserialize())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize) serialize and unserialize are explained