# How to show data from JSON string converted array

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel

I want to show some data from JSON string by making that string to array

I have used json_decode to convert the json string into an array. Here is my json string (dd):

```
"{"title":"W3Schools Online Web Tutorials","description":"w3schools.com","image":"http:\/\/www.w3schools.com\/images\/colorpicker.png","url":"https:\/\/www.w3schools.com\/"}"
```

When I am returning the array or dd the array, that showing me the array as I intended (dd):

```
array:4 [▼"title" => "W3Schools Online Web Tutorials""description" => "w3schools.com""image" => "http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png""url" => "https://www.w3schools.com/"]
```

But then when I am trying to show `$myarray->title` it is giving me error:

> Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

```
public function showDetail(Request $request){
    $rUrl = "http://api.linkpreview.net/?key=5c59318d927ca5c5b481c89a6c18a0a2623a61d568502&q=".$request->body;
    $json_string= file_get_contents($rUrl);
    $data= json_decode($json_string,true);
    return view('showIn')->with('data', $data);


}
```

**Expected result**: W3Schools Online Web Tutorials
**Actual result**: Error:Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Comment: Try `$myarray["title"]` (also, please stay away from w3schools, and remove the unrelated tags; this has nothing to do with javascript, ajax or laravel)

Comment: this is array and you are access like an object, you should access as `$myarray['title']`

Comment: Specify how you want to access the contents of the array. e.g $data['title']

Comment: I think you should use `serialize` and `unserialize` php function, put your array into serialize function, as when in the page you want, unserilize it. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string is in double quotes for one, use single quotes.

Secondly, `$myarray->title` is what you would do if you were working with an object. Since your working with an array, do it like `$myarray['title']`

This will work.

```
$myjson = '{"title": "W3Schools Online Web Tutorials", "description":"w3schools.com","image":"http:\/\/www.w3schools.com\/images\/colorpicker.png","url":"https:\/\/www.w3schools.com\/"}';

$myarray = json_decode($myjson, true);

echo $myarray['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an array so you should be able to access it like this `$data['title']`;

Answer (score 0):

You should use response json instead of return view('showIn')->with('data', $data);

```
return response()->json($data);
```

but if you want to print json in your view you can simply do

```
$rUrl = "http://api.linkpreview.net/?key=5c59318d927ca5c5b481c89a6c18a0a2623a61d568502&q=".$request->body;
$json_string= file_get_contents($rUrl);
return view('showIn')->with('json', $json_string);
```

In your blade template use

```
{{ $json }}
```