# How to extract data from (array?) with colons

Tags: php

The data structure when printed out using `print_r($my_value)` looks like this:

> a:4:{s:14:"address_line_1";s:14:"MY ADRES AND NUMBER";s:4:"city";s:8:"MY CITY";s:7:"country";s:7:"MY COUNTRY";s:8:"zip_code";s:4:"MY POSTAL CODE";}

I would like to extract all the 'MY ...' values.

How can I achieve this?

I can't find the specific data structure this is which makes it complicated searching this.

Comment: Looks like serialized data, have a look and see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed!