# How do I access this string

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just added some custom fields for users. So 'api' is one of them.

```
function abc(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    print_r(get_user_meta($current_user->id)['api'][0]);

}

add_action('init', 'abc');
```

And the result I get is a string:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:9:"paybphone";i:1;s:3:"ips";}
```

I don't know how to access "i" value from the PHP code as its string. And I also know its not JSON , so I also can't use 'json_encode()' function. Please help me out ! I am new to Wordpress programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use php serialize() and unserialize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize)

Comment: That's called a serialized string and the linked question explains its handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your result into the unserialize() function from php, it will return your PHP array that you can easily access after

More info : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php