# Is this Json Data, XML or Arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am confused on what kind of data is this. Can anyone help me on this. I am trying to make it in readable format using PHP.

```
a:6:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:9:"your-name";s:6:"Sujith";s:10:"your-email";s:21:"sudhamenon990@gmail.com";s:12:"your-subject";s:5:"Hello";s:12:"your-message";s:16:"How are you man?";s:16:"ywctm-product-id";s:4:"1840";}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is an array serialized by the PHP function `serialize()`, use this to decode it https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php, the `6` seems wrong however

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use php serialize() and unserialize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize)

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me check @Scuzzy and El_Vanja

Comment: Its working fine. Thx

Answer (score 0):

It is a serialized array. You need to unserialize it

```
unserialize ( string $data , array $options = [] )
```

unserialize() takes a single serialized variable and converts it back into a PHP value.So that you can access it using php.

Comment: Any Php script to unserialize?