# Can I know what is the regular expression to capture latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

```
"a:3:{s:3:\"lat\";s:9:\"5.9611959\";s:3:\"lng\";s:11:\"116.0973403\";s:7:\"address\";s:85:\"Lot No. GA1, GA2 & GA3, Ground Floor, City Mall, Kota Kinabalu, 88000 Sabah, Malaysia\";}"
```

This is the value returned from get_post_meta["wilcity_location"], how can i extract the 5.9611959 and 116.0973403?

Comment: That looks like serialized data, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize

Answer (score 1):

You have `serialised` data - you need to first use `unserialize` and analyse the underlying data structure - in this case an array.

```
$s="a:3:{s:3:\"lat\";s:9:\"5.9611959\";s:3:\"lng\";s:11:\"116.0973403\";s:7:\"address\";s:85:\"Lot No. GA1, GA2 & GA3, Ground Floor, City Mall, Kota Kinabalu, 88000 Sabah, Malaysia\";}";
$data=unserialize($s);
$lat=$data['lat'];
$lng=$data['lng'];

echo $lat, $lng;
```

Comment: If this does solve the problem, then it should be closed as a duplicate.