# How to Store Multidimensional Array in Mysql Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Hi I have an array of Services ordered by user like below $_POST values printed

```
Array
(
[compaignID] => 4
[totalChecked] => 3
[hear_about_us] => Google
[videolink] => 
[LinkedIn] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => http://developer.comoj.com
    )

[Facebook] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

[Twitter] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

[YouTube] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 4
        [2] => http://developer.comoj.com
    )

[Coupon_Area] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

[Website] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

[Google_Map] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

[Email] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 8
        [2] => http://developer.comoj.com
    )

[Share_To_Social_Media] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

[btnSubmit] => Submit
)
```

I'm confused how to store these. I made these arrays in php form to make their groups like below

for Orders Input field

```
<input name="<?php echo $service; ?>[]" type="text" id="order<?php echo $service; ?>" size="4">
```

for Services Check boxes to check which services to take

```
<input name="<?php echo $service; ?>[]" type="checkbox" id="show<?php echo $service; ?>" value="<?php echo $serviceID; ?>" onclick="countChecked();">
```

And for Services WebURL the input field below like

```
<input name="<?php echo $service; ?>[]" type="text" id="<?php echo $service; ?>" size="40">
```

I'm confused how to get only arrays which have values and store only these services their order number like for showing ascending or descending and their webrurls against each checked checkbox.

I'm confused how to loop through and store in mysql.

Please help me.

Many Thanks

Comment: It depends entirely on the structure of your tables. Post some schemas and maybe we can help you.

Comment: http://php.net/serialize

Comment: My Table is like below SQL `CREATE TABLE `tbl_page_links` (
  `pageLinkID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `compaignID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `serviceID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `webaddress` text NOT NULL,
  `sorder` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isActive` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pageLinkID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take help of `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` functions of PHP solve these things.

To store and array into `mysql`, you should use `json_encode($yourArray);` and you should store the returned string into `mysql`.

Similarly for retrieving, you should use `json_decode($yourMySqlStoredString)` and this will return the array back to you, which you can use for your further manupulations!

[json_encode php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[json_decode php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: +1 for awesome creative solution. Would have given you another 4 if I could. Well done.

Comment: -1 Terrible idea. Instead of shoving serialized data into a RDBMS you should adjust your schema to properly fit the data.

Comment: What if I try the PHP Serialize() & Unserialize(); Which one is better and easy to handle. also Fast enough.

Comment: @NullUserException but if you could read the question, probably that's not what user wants :)

Comment: I'll adjust it to store json or Serialize() & Unserialize() data.

Comment: @junjua serialize would be faster, but `json_encode` and `json_decode` could be used for several purposes, even the data could be used for different systems or communication. so its tradeoffs, performance or easy maintenance!

Comment: @NullUserException as you can see junjua concludes storing the data into json or serialize formats only, so thats what he indended by the question!, anyway thanks for your negative mark, though it didn't make any sense!

Comment: I've read the question. It sounds like the OP wants to have multiple one-to-many relationships; which shouldn't be handled by using serialization (eg: using json or php's built-in `serialize()`)

Comment: you could refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306740/json-vs-serialized-array-in-database) for your json vs serialize stuff :)

Comment: And regardless of whether the OP feel that it "will work," we should advise him or her against bad coding practices (eg: inserting serialized data into RDBMS)

Comment: more than a practice, it's a matter of requirement :), for now, if I am not concerned with the relationship but just storing snapshots, why should I choose unwanted complexities? is over-engineering stuffs really necessary? anyways, the discussions will have no end, so you are the winner!

Answer (score 6):

I believe **the use of [serialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions is better than using `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`**.

The reason is simple: Serialize encodes multidimensional (string)indexed array into string and unserialize is able to return the same array (in original array format) unlike the combination of json_encode and json_decode function which returns object with array properties.

Well and that is simply not very "programmer friendly".

Original array:

```
Array(
[prvni] => Array
    (
        [druhy] => Array
            (
                [0] => a
                [1] => b
                [2] => c
                [3] => d
                [4] => e
                [5] => f
            )
    )

[prvnidruhy] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
    )
)
```

json_encode:

```
{"prvni":{"druhy":["a","b","c","d","e","f"]},"prvnidruhy":[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

json_decode:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
 public 'prvni' => 
  object(stdClass)[2]
   public 'druhy' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
      2 => string 'c' (length=1)
      3 => string 'd' (length=1)
      4 => string 'e' (length=1)
      5 => string 'f' (length=1)
   public 'prvnidruhy' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
      3 => int 4
      4 => int 5
```

serialize:

```
a:2:{s:5:"prvni";a:1:{s:5:"druhy";a:6:{i:0;s:1:"a";i:1;s:1:"b";i:2;s:1:"c";i:3;s:1:"d";i:4;s:1:"e";i:5;s:1:"f";}}s:10:"prvnidruhy";a:5:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;}}
```

unserialize:

```
array (size=2)
 'prvni' => 
    array (size=1)
 'druhy' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
      2 => string 'c' (length=1)
      3 => string 'd' (length=1)
      4 => string 'e' (length=1)
      5 => string 'f' (length=1)
 'prvnidruhy' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
      3 => int 4
      4 => int 5
```

Answer (score 1):

But you could use `json_decode($data, true)` obtaining a simple associative array. 
From the [documentation](http://php.net/json_decode):

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: Thank you for review frostnational, I'm not so pratical!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on your last comment. You need to loop through the array and insert each value. Tentative...

```
foreach ($array AS $v) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_page_link` (serviceID, sorder, webaddress) VALUES ($v[0], $v[1], '$v[2]')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```