# CakePHP: Saving a File Field with Expanded Data Array to DB

Tags: arrays, file, cakephp, upload

When uploading files you usually get an array created for the field. For example in the case where the model is **Document** and field is **submittedfile**:

```
$this->request->data['Document']['submittedfile'] = array(
'name' => 'conference_schedule.pdf',
'type' => 'application/pdf',
'tmp_name' => 'C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/php1EE.tmp',
'error' => 0,
'size' => 41737,
);
```

The array cannot be saved to the DB because the field cannot save the **'submittedfile'** array to the DB **'submittedfile'**  column. However I only need the **name** section of the above array in the **submittedfile** field of the DB. Tried a number of ways here are two:

**1** Turning the submittedfile from array to string **in the Controller Method** before calling the save method in Controller Methdod. (Issue could not use cakePHP validate for fileSize and uploadError as they require ['tmp_name'] to work.)

```
public function addDocument(){
$this->request->data['Document']['submittedfile'] = $this->request->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name'];
$this->Document->save($this->request->data);}
```

**2** Turning the submittedfile from array to string **in the beforeSave Callback Method** before calling the save method in Controller Method. (Issue is that I get Error **Illegal string offset 'name'**)

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()){
$this->data['Document']['submittedfile'] = $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name'];}
```

Any answers for saving uploaded file type arrays to DB?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the array, you can [store it as JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or as a [serialized array](http://php.net/serialize%E2%80%8E).

There is a discussion about the advantages of each one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306740/json-vs-serialized-array-in-database)

Regarding your two solutions, maybe the second one is better.

Inside the `beforeSave`, please `debug($this->data);` to see exactly what you are getting, and how you can access `'name'`

How are you handling the file upload? That should be treated separately: upload the file with a random name and store that name in the database.

Comment: I was using the debug as you suggested found it gave the following.

Comment: I was using the debug as you suggested but it gave me the array structure. It showed that using `$this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']` should return the correct value. The problem seems to be with the assignment to `$this->data['Document']['submittedfile']` because if I echo `$this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']` the value is shown without the **Illegal offset error**.ted found it gave the following.

Comment: Sorry about the first comment clicked enter by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what will you do with just the name in the db, you need to upload the file too I guess.

Use this: [Uploader](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem: Multiple Save Methods in the controller** that used different `$this->data` arrays. Tried to simplify the code posted and took out the issue from the code. The original code not shown contained two save() methods called within the `adddocument()` controller and one did not have the `$this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']` passed to it. This caused the **illegal string offset error**:

**Tip 1**(recommended):

**Use isset()** to check that the variable exists before trying to manipulate it in the **beforeSave()** method:

```
public function beforeSave($options=array())
{
  if(isset($this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']))
  {$this->data['Document']['submittedfile'] = $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name'];
  }
   return true;
}
```

**Tip 2**:

**Disable Callbacks** (i.e. beforeSave, afterValidate etc.) being called by other save methods in the controller. If those saves don't require manipulation of their data beforeSave:

```
$this->Document->saveField('submittedfile', $yourvalue, array('callbacks'=>false))
```

Thanks to all those that took time to help me out @cornelb and @skywalker.