# How can i read a text file which contains a proper array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, robots.txt

I used  this to write a array into a text file:

```
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, print_r($newStrings, TRUE));
fclose($fp);
```

now i want to read it back in php just like i would read a normal array? how do i do it? I'm fairly new to this and im currently on a deadline to get something related tot this fixed, pls help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) would be valid PHP code that you could then `include` and work better than `print_r()`, but I recommend using JSON / [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) would also work similar to JSON but isn't portable.

**Write:**

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', json_encode($newStrings));
```

**Read:**

```
$newStrings = json_decode(file_get_contents('file.txt'), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to do this.

Writing to file:

```
$myArray = ['test','test2','test3'];
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, serialize($myArray));
fclose($fp);
```

Or slimmer:

```
file_put_contents('file.txt',serialize($myArray));
```

Reading it again:

```
$myArray = unserialize(file_get_contents('file.txt'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use json_encode() or serialize() on the data when you write it and then use json_decode() or unserialize() on the data when you have read it.

To see the differences check this question:
[JSON vs. Serialized Array in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306740/json-vs-serialized-array-in-database)