# better way for insert data to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, json, serialization

I need to design database table for article reviews.

First way :

```
|id|name|email|date|ip|article_id|avatar|user_id|review_field_1|review_field_2|review_field_3|review_field_4|review_field_5|review_field_6|
```

result: using normal query

Second Way:

```
|id|article_id|serialize_data|
```

method: `serialize` / `unserialize`

OR:

```
|id|article_id|json_data|.
```

method: `json_encode` / `json_decode`

which way is better and faster ?!

Comment: Your answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306740/json-vs-serialized-array-in-database#1721191

Comment: It depends on how will you use that data later.