# In PHP, why is json_encode way slower than serialize?

Tags: php, serialization, json

I don't get it, the data produced by `json_encode` is much more straightforward than `serialize` and yet both the JSON encode and decode functions are much more slower than the `serialize` and `unserialize` counterparts. **Why?**

Comment: in which way is JSON much more straightforward then php-native serialize, when you see it from the point of view of a computer. I think JSON more straightforward, but only for humans.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize

Comment: @David: Yes, I'm aware, thanks! ;)

Answer (score 14):

`json_encode` does string parsing and tons of allocs compared to `serialize`'s `memcpy`

Have fun in the [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/json/json_encoder.c) if you're really in the mood.

Comment: So does that make JSON safer for multi-byte strings?

Comment: Looks like the source for [json_encode](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/json/json_encoder.c) vs [serialize](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/var.c) Looks tidy code but I can't read C well !