# Serialize/unserialize PHP object-graph to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, serialization, reference

I wanted to serialize a complete PHP object-graph to a JSON string representation, and unserialize it back to an identical PHP object-graph.

Here is a summary of options I considered, and reasons why they don't work for me:

- `serialize()` doesn't do what I want, because it uses a format specific to PHP. I want a format that is widely supported by most languages, and human-readable/editable.
- `json_encode()` doesn't do what I want, because it only does simple values and arrays, not objects. (I'm actually using this in my implementation, see below.)
- `var_export()` doesn't handle circular references, and doesn't do what I want (see above.) *(note that my current implementation does not handle circular references either - see comments and reply below for clarification of this issue.)*
- Sebastian Bergmann's [Object Freezer](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-object-freezer) is a nice implementation, but it doesn't do what I want either - it uses a very long form, and relies on stuffing serialized objects with GUIDs.
- [Serialized](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized) doesn't do what I want - it does not actually perform serialization, it parses the output of `serialize()` and produces a different representation, e.g. XML, but is unable to parse that representation. (it also does not support JSON - XML is very long form, and is not what I want.)

I now have a working implementation to share:

https://github.com/mindplay-dk/jsonfreeze

The JSON-representation of the object-graph looks like this:

```
{
    "#type": "Order",
    "orderNo": 123,
    "lines": [{
        "#type": "OrderLine",
        "item": "milk \"fuzz\"",
        "amount": 3,
        "options": null
    }, {
        "#type": "OrderLine",
        "item": "cookies",
        "amount": 7,
        "options": {
            "#type": "#hash",
            "flavor": "chocolate",
            "weight": "1\/2 lb"
        }
    }],
    "paid": true
}
```

This approach is designed to work for a pure tree-structure aggregate - circular references are not allowed, nor multiple references to the same objects. In other words, this is not general-purpose like e.g. `serialize()` and `unserialize()` which function for any PHP object-graph.

In my [initial approach](https://gist.github.com/2630741/17041e14f58c8c2ecc30b1dabdfe5e8f87460412) I used a serialized form that was essentially a base-0 list of objects. The first object in the list (number 0) is the root of the serialized object-graph, any other objects are stored in the order they're found.

In the current implementation, the JSON representation resembles the original tree-structure to the extend that this is possible, making it possible to actually work with the JSON representation of an object-graph in JavaScript. The only deviation is the magic `#type` property (prefixed with # to prevent collision with property-names) and the `#hash` "type", used to distinguish `array`-type hashes (stored as JSON objects) from regular `array`-type arrays (stored as JSON arrays).

---

*I'm leaving these notes about the previous version here for historical purposes.*

Circular references are handled simply by never storing nested objects inside the serialized representation of each object - instead, any object-reference is stored as a JSON-object with the object-index - e.g. `{"__oref":2}` is a reference to the object with index `2` in the object-list.

I'm having a problem with array-references in my implementation - when I var_dump() inside the code that restores references to objects to the array, they are being populated, but at some point the array gets copied, and you end up with the empty copy. I've tried placing `&` characters everywhere in the code, but regardless of where I pass by reference, the end-result is an empty array.

Comment: I would not call the serialize format of PHP proprietary as it's documented - [at least inside the source-code](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/var.c#php_var_serialize_intern) - but as well by third parties. So you can use it.

Comment: it may be documented, but PHP is the only platform/language that has an implementation of unserialize() - I'd prefer JSON which is already supported by every mainstream language. And also is human-readable.

Comment: You can convert serialized data into XML which is supported everywhere. The [Serialized Library](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized) does this. It should not be that hard to extend it with a json dumper btw. - so maybe you find it useful.

Comment: XML is very long form - I need a compact format. Extending this library is a possibility, although that would be a lot like starting over. What I have here is _almost_ done.

I don't see a test or example demonstrating support for circular reference - do you know if that is supported?

Comment: It support what serialize in PHP supports, that is recursion and resursive references. The format is hierarchical - not flat as yours. As written, PHP's serialize supports complex types like objects and they can be nested.

Comment: At closer inspection, this library doesn't appear to perform serialization? Rather, it appears to parse and transform the output from the `serialize()` function, and the transformation is one-way - it can produce XML, but it can't parse the XML and turn it back into an actual object, as far as I can tell. I don't think this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'd like to point out also that storing in hierarchical form only makes sense when you're expecting a pure tree - but an object-graph may contain shared references. Take [this graph](http://cosketch.com/Saved/pP1zcswa) for example - how would you decide where to store C? A and B are equally important in this graph, neither has "ownership" of C. Your aggregate-root will always be stored as the first object in serialized form, but only because you identified it as the root when you serialized it - storing in hierarchical form would make sense for trees, but I expect to store graphs.

Comment: The PHP serialized form does this similary, next to the hierachical information it also tracks the numerical index of each value and can therefore reference it - if there is a reference. This will also take care that the first native PHP reference is the actual value in the serialized form and each next reference/alias will be referenced to the numerical position. For your task you might be interested in [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/spl_object_hash) to keep track of already serialized objects - as it looks like you're only concerned about objects.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need object identity for what I'm doing. And for the record, `spl_object_hash()` does _not_ work as a means of identification, because it reuses the hash-keys anytime you delete an object - that's why Sebastian Bergmann's Object Freezer injects GUIDs. There is no way to uniquely identify an object in PHP - this has been brought up and complained about many times over the years...

Comment: That's true (and known), but your serialization should be one transaction, so that - as you know the shortcomming - should not be an issue writing the implementation.

Comment: Should you put a new parameter informing the type of the new object so you can make it descend? This way you will have the methods of the desired class

Comment: @EASI I have no idea what you're asking. Descend from what? Why do you care about methods? Have a look at the [completed library implementation](https://github.com/mindplay-dk/jsonfreeze).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finished script (posted above) meets my precise requirements:

- Serialize and unserialize an entire aggregate.
- Have a JSON representation that closely resembles the original data-structure.
- Do not pollute the data-structure with dynamically generated keys or other data.

It does not handle circular references. As pointed out in a [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489876/serialize-unserialize-php-object-graph-to-json-partially-working-solution-need#comment13570677_10489876) there is no right way to store circular references or multiple references to the same object, as these are all equal. Realizing this, I decided my object-graph must be a regular tree, and accepted this limitation as "a good thing".

**update**: the ouput can now be formatted with indentation, newlines and whitespace - it was important for me to have a human-readable (and source-control friendly) representation for my purposes. (The formatting can be enabled or disabled as needed.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are after, but if you are only interested in getting at public properties of a object, get_object_vars($obj) will do the trick.

```
<?php

class foo {
    public $fname = "John";
    public $sname = "Doe";
    private $status = null;
    static $type = "person";


}

$obj = new foo;

print_r( (get_object_vars($obj)) );

print json_encode(get_object_vars($obj));

?>
```

Will output :

Array ( [fname] => John [sname] => Doe )

{"fname":"John","sname":"Doe"}

The above method is useless for accessing function references and private variables but you might be able to use this in conjunction with some more code to knock up what you want.

Dinesh.

Comment: If you looked at the implementation I posted, I got quite a bit further than that...