# What is the quickest way to save an array to disk in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to save an array to disk so that I can easily read it back into an array. What would be an easy way to do this?

Comment: ...information?  It's an array of associative arrays.

Comment: Strings? Numbers? Objects? Ponies?

Comment: An array of associative arrays of strings. array[0] = array('pony id' => "127tk", 'pony owner' => "me", 'pony size' => "little")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
file_put_contents($file, serialize($array));
```

And read it back by

```
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
```

**Edit:**
You can also use json_encode/json_decode instead. Check this question [Preferred method to store PHP arrays (json_encode vs serialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize) to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) is not guaranteed to be portable between different applications - it's ONLY designed to be readable by PHP.  PHP don't even guarantee that it will be portable between different PHP versions.

Therefore, [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) is great for local temporary data because it's fast, but if you want something to be more permanent, and highly portable, I'd use [`json_encode()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Then use [`json_decode()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), obviously, to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

For a benchmark test of three methods -JSON, serialization, var_export- see [http://techblog.procurios.nl](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/618/news/view/34972/14863/cache-a-large-array-json-serialize-or-var_export.html)
JSON is probably best for large (>50 Mb) arrays although it works only with UTF-8 encoded data.