# Best way to write arrays to a file?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to avoid writing to DB and use constants/array for lang files etc.

i.e:

```
$lang = array (
  'hello' => 'hello world!'
);
```

and be able to edit it from the back office.
(then instead of fetching it from the poor db, i would just use $lang['hello']..).

what are you suggesting for the best and efficient way to pull it of?

Comment: How about [`var_export()`](http://uk.php.net/var_export)?

Comment: do u want to know whats more efficient, storing in DB or storing in arrays?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize

Comment: How about an established l10n system like gettext?

Comment: Why do you think your database is poor? My database is rather good at storing and retrieving values, because... oh yeah, that's what it's supposed to do :)

Comment: I've added a coded example below on my answer. Please consider to accept an answer if you're satisfied with one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely JSON

To save it :

```
file_put_contents("my_array.json", json_encode($array));
```

To get it back :

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("my_array.json"));
```

As simple as that !

Comment: Please note that if you want to save disk space (when using very large arrays ie) you can always store it in files as binary data

Answer (score 19):

the most efficient way i found looks like this:

build up your array in php somehow and export it into a file using `var_export()`

```
file_put_contents( '/some/file/data.php', '<?php return '.var_export( $data_array, true ).";\n" );
```

then later, wherever you need this data pull it like this

```
$data = include '/some/file/data.php';
```

Comment: i would prefer serialize over var_export. An attacker could put malicious code into the .php containing the variables and it gets executed.

Comment: @Mogria Well, if an attacker has access to the language files, he presumably could inject that code into any other file as well... :)

Comment: @deceze not necessarily, the file you write these variables to needs to be writeable for php. The other files only need to be readable.

Comment: you don't need to write the file from a script which is accessible from the outside. the most efficient and fast way to read data arrays is this include. serialize/unserialize needs more memory and cpu and even bytes in the file.

Answer (score 6):

Well if you insist to put the data into files, you might consider php functions `serialize()` and `unserialize()` and then put the data into files using `file_put_contents`.

Example:

```
<?php
$somearray = array( 'fruit' => array('pear', 'apple', 'sony') );
file_put_contents('somearray.dat', serialize( $somearray ) );
$loaded = unserialize( file_get_contents('somearray.dat') );

print_r($loaded);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`.

`$save = json_encode($array);`

write contents of $save to file

To load lang use:

```
$lang = file_get_contents('langfile');
$lang = json_decode($lang, true);
```