# which is faster , serialization , ini or XML

Tags: php

I am trying to read/write a one dimensional array into a file. Which is faster method to do this for read/replace?

- Serializing the array into the file, then loading it back again
- Using XML
- Using INI

Thank you

Comment: The only reliable way is to benchmark and find out. Unless the file is going to be 100kb big, the difference is probably going to be negligeable though

Comment: the array is about 1000 elements , each element have 100 chars max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it depends on the data types and how you use it.
There is one more method you haven't mentioned: JSON (if you don't have to save the data types, takes less space than serialized array).
This may help:  [Preferred method to store PHP arrays (json_encode vs serialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize)

Comment: did a small test on xml , ini , serialize and json . json was the fastest