# How to store data in db in array form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, serialization

i want to store my PHP values in db(mysql) in the form of array...

for example

```
$a=array{10,20,30,40};
```

i want to store this variable **$a** in to db in the array form like how it's storing in array using index.

why i want to do this because in future i may have to perform update or delete operation on the array values..

i know that it's possible to do this thing... but i don't know how to implement this..

i searched about this topic but i didn't get proper answer....

Please suggest me how to do this things...

Comment: Try to use json_encode

Comment: plz give example of output  .

Comment: @NitishKumar for example i store my above value in db in the form of string like {10,20,30,40} and then i may have to update/delete 20 from the string or i may have to add new value...

Comment: use implode(',',$a) see this link once http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: @nickle it won't work in this situation..

Comment: then store individual values in a table so that you can make edit or delete easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't use [**json_encode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP and store it on your database. It's the best way.

The array will be converted to a string and will be stored.
Retrieve the data and make use of [**json_decode**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then start working as per your needs.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

> **OUTPUT:**
>  {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

Comment: i want to store it in db in single attributes.. and my question is in db how to store?

Comment: When you pass the array to json_encode, it will be converted into a string, you can directly store that into the database.

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ, You need to read this thread before downvoting. Performance of json_encode vs serialize. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize

Answer (score 2):

You should create a distinct **TABLE** to store this kind of data.
Consists of 2 columns, corresponding record ID and the actual data.

So, your record will be looks like

```
rid value
1   10
1   20
1   30
1   40
2   10
2   40
...
```

this way you will be able to perform update or delete operation on the array values using **conventional SQL routines**, as well as selecting data based on the array values.

This is how the things done oin the real world, not in PHP sandbox.

## All othe answers here are plainly wrong

Answer (score -1):

I would use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)/[unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) for this. You can use it like this:

### Send to MySQL

```
<?php
    $a = array{10,20,30,40};
    $a = serialize($a);
    // your code here to send it to the mysql
?>
```

### Get from MySQL

```
<?php
    // your code here to collect it from mysql
    $a = unserialize($mysql->str);
?>
```

The field in the MySQL should be TEXT or VARCHAR.

Regards

BlackBonjour

Comment: What about fixing the essentially flawed approach?

Answer (score -2):

You can always [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) your array then store the result in a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` field and after fetching you can [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) the field.