# how to pass json or class object to command line php script

Tags: php, bash, oop, shell, command-line

I have

```
$client = new Google_Client();
```

And it's token in json.

Now I want to pass this client object as well as json token to another script via shell_exec().
Let's assume command as

```
php myscript.php var1 var2 $client $token
```

Now as command line takes all argument as string I am not able to pass the json and client object.  For json I found `serialize()` and `unserialize()` functions that I can pass to command prompt but what about `$client` object how to pass it to command prompt? Please Help.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to `shell_exec()` a php script from another php script ? It would be much simpler if you include it, this sounds a bad idea.

Comment: I have a long polling script and so that want to run it from shell it will be in background. But need to pass the client,Now I am thinking rather than passing all this why not re-authenticate $_GET['code'] returned from google. :)

Comment: but problem is that there it is giving error 'invalid grant' as code is already authenticated by front end code.

Comment: I think the issue is you're wanting to send an address that is referencing `new Google_Client()`. I'm not sure if that's possible, although it may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of tricky.

First and foremost, if you want to pass exactly the same object to another script, why dont you `include` it? Or create some function to run instead?

Second, why don't you create your object in that script? It would save you a lot of trouble.

If you absolutely have to pass the object to another script via shell_exec, you may use the `serialize()` function, but there are a few caveats:

1. Of course you have to escape it, e.g. with `escapeshellarg`
2. If your object contains any resources (such as `fopen` handle, directly or indirectly), they will not be serialized and thus you will lose them
3. Your script must be aware of yout Google_Client class definition, and definition of any class that it contains reference to. Otherwise it will be unserialized as __PHP_Incomplete_Class and effectively unusable.

check the manual page [serialize](https://www.php.net/serialize)

> serialize() handles all types, except the
> resource-type. You can even serialize() arrays that contain references
> to itself. Circular references inside the array/object you are
> serializing will also be stored. Any other reference will be lost.
> When serializing objects, PHP will attempt to call the member function
> __sleep() prior to serialization. This is to allow the object to do any last minute clean-up, etc. prior to being serialized. Likewise,
> when the object is restored using unserialize() the __wakeup() member
> function is called.

and the one for [unserialize](https://www.php.net/unserialize)

> Note: unserialize_callback_func directive It's possible to set a
> callback-function which will be called, if an undefined class should
> be instantiated during unserializing. (to prevent getting an
> incomplete object "__PHP_Incomplete_Class".) Use your php.ini,
> ini_set() or .htaccess to define 'unserialize_callback_func'.
> Everytime an undefined class should be instantiated, it'll be called.
> To disable this feature just empty this setting.

Comment: it' did not solved my problem, facing some other issue of google api service account, I was already knowing serialize and unserialize but thanks for sharing escapeshellarg. :)

Comment: sure! If you think it answers the original question, do not hesitate to mark it as an accepted answer; If you have some issues with google api, I think you should open another question.

Answer (score 6):

Serialize will also "stringify" objects! You can also base64 encode/decode your arguments to prevent special chars troubles :

```
$aArgs = array($client, $token);
$sArgs = base64_encode(serialize($aArgs));
exec('php myscript.php '.$sArgs);
```

Comment: Use [`escapeshellarg`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.escapeshellarg.php), not `base64_encode`.

Comment: Yeah sure, but escapeshellarg may have troubles with serialized data => http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php#109514

Answer (score 3):

I'd use json_encode():

[Preferred method to store PHP arrays (json_encode vs serialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize)

TLDR? There are some possible issues with json_encode():

- By default, json_encode() converts UTF-8 characters to Unicode escape
  sequences while serialize() does not. Note: To leave UTF-8 characters
  untouched, you can use the option JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE as of PHP
  5.4.
- JSON will have no memory of what the object's original class was (they are always restored as instances of stdClass).
- You can't leverage __sleep() and __wakeup() with JSON
- Only public properties are serialized with JSON
- JSON is more portable

But if none of these things are an issue for your use case. it's 100-150% faster than serialize(). (Your Google_Client() class will be converted to a standard class when you decode the string).

```
// Script that kicks off the background task
$aArgs = array($client, $token);
$sArgs = base64_encode(json_encode($aArgs));
exec('php myscript.php '.$sArgs . ' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');

// myscript.php
$sArgs = json_decode(base64_decode($argv[1]));
// do something with $sArgs here...
```