# how to make adminEmail dynamically in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

currently the adminEmail is set in the params.php file. I am trying to change the 'adminEmail' dynamically and then I can assign the email value I want. There is the code in the params.php.

```
return array(
    // this is displayed in the header section
    'title' => 'title here',
    // this is admin email
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@email.com',
```

But the admin emails can be more than one(eg. admin1@email.com, admin2@email.com), how can I set admin email dynamically in params.php ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try set multiple emails on adminEmail, and at runtime access it using index. E.G

```
//asign multiple email ids to adminEmail as array
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>array('webmaster@example.com','sany@gmail.com','xxx@yahoo.com','webmaster2@example.com')
),

//access it using array index at runtime as your requirement
<?php echo Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'][1];?>  //sany@gmail.com
<?php echo Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'][2];?>  // xxx@yahoo.com
```

OR

Create a static method on a class that will generate dynamic email ids and 
then set it to your adminEmail param .e.g

```
class Email
      {
    public static function generateEmailIds()
    {
      //or any other way to generate email ids or id
              return array('webmaster@example.com',
              'sany@gmail.com',
              'xxx@yahoo.com');
    }
}
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>Email::generateEmailIds(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, although I don't recommend this approach, what you want to do can be done like this:

- You need to store your array in a file in *serialized* form (that is, call function [serialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) on it. That will turn the array into a string.
- You can read the file and *unserialize* it (that is, call function [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on it. That will turn the string that you read form file back into a PHP array.)

  ```
  $handle = fopen('path/to/file','rb');
  $contents = fread($handle,999).
  $array = unserialize($contents);
  ```
- set `'adminEmail'` to what you want it to be:

  ```
  $array['adminEmail'] = 'new@email.com;
  ```

  or even

  ```
  $array['adminEmail']= array(..lots of emails..);
  ```
- then you need to turn the array into a string and write the array back to file. Like this, for example:

  ```
  $serialized_contents = serialize($array);
  fwrite($handle, $serialized_contents);
  ```

[There may be more efficient ways to do this if you  want to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize)