# MySQL save array in the db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is it possible to store an associative array as it is in the db?

```
array(
       key  => value,
       key2 => value2,
       key3 => value3,
       ...
      )
```

Currently, if I write `fieldname = '$array'`, only the string "Array" is stored in the field.

Comment: you will need to flatten it serialize could work or some encode / decode method

Comment: @kevinabelita. the array keys are not the same as the fields in db table.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize) might give some perspective, this does not cover database insertion though, please avoid `mysql_`

Comment: @Anigel, json encoding / decoding will just do fine. Thankyou for the suggestion.

Comment: yes! in my case, json encode / decode is the way indeed! Thanks @kevinabelita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
fieldname = json_encode($array);
```

and when you want to retrieve from database then use

```
$array = json_decode($fieldname);
```

Comment: this is in fact solved it! My bad, I was not thinking that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
serialize($array);
```

and then when you fetch it from the database:

```
unserialize($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do use

```
$fieldname = json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    php code to store array in database
    <?
        $array_string = array(key => value, key2 => value2, key3 => value3);
        $conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
        mysql_select_db("mysql_db",$conn);
        $array_string=mysql_escape_string(serialize($array));
        mysql_query("insert into table (column) values($array_string)",$conn);
    ?>

    To retrieve array from database

    <?
        $conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
        mysql_select_db("mysql_db",$conn);
        $q=mysql_query("select column from table",$conn);
        while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
        $array= unserialize($rs['column']);
        print_r($array);
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It is other way than using json encode / decode.