# Php: How to echo json_encode as soon as it gets generated

Tags: php, performance, serialization, json

For a rest API, I need to serialize big and deeply nested json objects;

Is there a way to echo the json *while* it is generated?

If I echo `json_encode($var)` , it will generate the whole json and *then* spit it out: it costs memory, and I have to wait for the whole generation to be complete, before I start to see some response in my browser.

Is there any way to force json_decode to have this kind of behaviour?

Or are there libraries that can do this kind of stuff?

Comment: No. Unless you want to roll your own encoder. a JSON-encoded data structure of any reasonable amount of complexity is going to be a huge mess of nested `[ ... ]` and `{ .... }` pairs. outputting on the go is possible, but you're highly likely to end up with partial/corrupt strings at the other end, especially if the encoding process causes an OOM condition or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to iterate over the object you are encoding and to encode it item by item, probably writing your own json notation to contain the generated json.

For example

```
echo "["; // or { for an associative array (don't forget to output the json_encode()d keys and their colons)
$first = true;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++) {
    // json does not support trailing commas like php does
    // and you can't do an implode(",", $array) here because of the memory usage
    if ($first) {
        $first = false;
    } else {
        echo ",";
    }
    echo json_encode($i);
}
echo "]"; // or }
```

taken from here:
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/288266-json-encode-exceeds-allowed-memory/

Answer (score -2):

You can use smarty template to put json just reading file from disk. 
Or you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820537/3900160

Comment: You can improve this answer by giving an explicit example about how to use "smarty template" to echo the JSON upon encoding.

Comment: Are you sure smarty templates are generated on the fly and not stored in memory before being pushed to http?