# PHP - json_encode not printing object

Tags: php, class, object, private, public

I have two classes `ServiceDetails` and `AvailableServices`

```
class ServiceDetails {
    private $service_name;
    private $price;
    private $currency_id;
    public function __construct($service_name, $price, $currency_id) {
        $this->service_name = $service_name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->currency_id = $currency_id;
    }
}

class AvailableServices {
    public $services;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->services = [];
    }
}
```

I created an instance of `AvailableServices` and added an object of class `ServiceDetails` into the `$services` array of the `AvailableServices` instance.

```
$services = new AvailableServices();
$service_details = new ServiceDetails($a, $b, $c);
$services->services[] = clone $service_details;
```

I `var_dump` the `$services` object and it outputs correctly. However, when I do `json_encode`, nothing outputs except the `services` property of `AvailableServices`.

```
var_dump($services); // something
echo json_encode($services); // nothing
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For `json_encode` to print out properties, those properties must be `public`. Changing the `ServiceDetails` to use `public` instead of `private` resolved the issue.

```
class ServiceDetails {
    public $service_name;
    public $price;
    public $currency_id;
    public function __construct($service_name, $price, $currency_id) {
        $this->service_name = $service_name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->currency_id = $currency_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer here is to implement [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface for `ServiceDetails` class.

```
class ServiceDetails implements JsonSerializable{
    private $service_name;
    private $price;
    private $currency_id;
    public function __construct($service_name, $price, $currency_id) {
        $this->service_name = $service_name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->currency_id = $currency_id;
    }

    /**
     * Returns JSON representation
     * 
     * @return array|mixed
     */
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }    
}
```

Comment: There isn't really a 'correct' method. It depends on what you're looking for. My answer isn't wrong per se. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/804045/2317532