# PHP read array declaration from file?

Tags: bash, php, arrays

I've got a text file with an array declaration (actually an array of arrays) that I'm reading into my PHP using `'file_get_contents'`.  The PHP code is treating the contents that it reads from the file as a literal string, rather than creating an array.  I need to actually create the array.

Example:

The file `'probe2.csv'` contains the following text:

```
array(array(22, 296), array(43, 667), array(64, 1008), array(84, 1273), array(105, 1520), array(126, 1899), array(146, 2149))
```

My PHP is:

```
$s1 = array(array(22, 256), array(43, 524), array(64, 797), array(84, 1133), array(105, 1515), array(126, 1813), array(146, 2128));
$s2 = file_get_contents('probe2.csv');
print_r($s1);
echo "<p>";
print_r($s2);
echo "</p>";
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22 [1] => 256 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 43 [1] => 524 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 64 [1] => 797 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 84 [1] => 1133 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 105 [1] => 1515 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 126 [1] => 1813 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 146 [1] => 2128 ) )

array(array(22, 296), array(43, 667), array(64, 1008), array(84, 1273), array(105, 1520), array(126, 1899), array(146, 2149))
```

I'm a bash guy, not a PHP guy, so I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: I suggest to you (as PHP developer in the past) read about 'get from csv'(http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and about data serialisation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). It's really very simple. PHP has couple of library functions that read formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, you should you need to change it like this:

```
<?php
$s2 = array(array(22, 296), array(43, 667), array(64, 1008), array(84, 1273), array(105, 1520), array(126, 1899), array(146, 2149));
```

And then, in you main php file, just include it:

```
include('probe2.php');
```

If you have no control about the probe2 file, you can do this (it's bad practice, but works):

```
$temp = file_get_contents('probe2.csv');
eval('$s2 = ' . $temp . ';');
```

$s2 will have the right array from here.

Comment: You should really consider using serialisation or a _proper_ data format instead though, if you have the option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize might help with choosing