# JSON_ENDODE why use to pass a PHP array?

Tags: php, json

I want to convert an array of objects to JSON encoding, but how it is possible to encode PHP array into JSON array.

Comment: Do you have a problem with  using `json_encode($your_array)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preferred method to store PHP arrays (json\_encode vs serialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize)

Comment: if you type "encode PHP array into JSON array" into google you get the answer straight away. Why did you bother waiting for us to tell you??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to convert php array into json
use:

```
json_encode($array);
```

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

for decode

```
json_decode($array);
```

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)